# Normalization correction using group_by() and creating new values from the operation

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is like this (this is an example data frame):

```
id_row  sample  wsts (xc)_mean  wstm (xc)_mean  label   tube
1       Ta      2937.5      4082.5      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4
2       Ta      3048        5347.5      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4
3       Ca      6176        7735.5      well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4
4       Ca      8431        13793       well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4
7       blank   2723        2359        well_1  blank
8       blank   3456        8777        well_2  blank
```

I need to perform the following operation:

1. Check the columns that contain "_mean" and apply the following operation: `current value - blank current value`. This operation must follow the values from the label column. For example, for label column values equal to "well_1":

```
(well_1):
2937.5 - 2723
3048 - 2723
(well_2):
6176 - 4985
8431 - 3456
```

2. If the operation is comparing blank with blank, keep the same value in the new column, for example:
   (well_1)
   2723 - 2723
   I do not need to do nothing, just keep the value in the same column.
3. After the operation was calculated create a new column with the extension "_norm" from the original column with numerical values, for example: `wsts (xc)_mean ---> wsts (xc)_norm`

Previously I used a similar approach, that involved the following part of an previous code:

```
dataframe %>%
group_by(label) %>%
     mutate(across(contains("_mean"),
     ..., 
     .name = "{str_replace(.col, '_mean', '_norm')}"
```

The ... represent the operation that I'm trying to apply, which is

```
current value (well_X) - current blank value (well_X), where X is 1 or 2.
```

The condition is always do the operation with well_x = well_x.
If I'm comparing the same value like this:

```
current blank value - current blank value, like 2723 - 2723
```

I just need to pass, and keep the same value in the new column.
So my expected result:

```
id_row  sample  wsts (xc)_mean ... label   tube wsts (xc)_norm
1       Ta      2937.5      ...      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4 214.5
2       Ta      3048        ...      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4 325
3       Ca      6176        ...      well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4 2720
4       Ca      8431        ...       well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4 4975
7       blank   2723        ...        well_1  blank 2723
8       blank   3456        ...        well_2  blank 3456
```

Here, I put the "..." only for a short example result.

What can I do to get this done? So far, I could not find a way to perform that.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data using `dput`, e.g. by running `dput(head(dataframe))` and pasting the output into the body of your question? I can't tell how the columns are meant to align to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `if_else` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(stringr)

dat %>%
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("_mean"),
    ~ if_else(tube == "blank", .x, .x - .x[tube == "blank"]),
    .names = "{str_replace(.col, '_mean', '_norm')}"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#> # Groups:   label [2]
#>   id_row sample `wsts (xc)_mean` `wstm (xc)_mean` label  tube   `wsts (xc)_norm`
#>    <int> <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>  <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1      1 Ta                2938.            4082. well_1 S_PUC…             214.
#> 2      2 Ta                3048             5348. well_1 S_PUC…             325 
#> 3      3 Ca                6176             7736. well_2 S_PUC…            2720 
#> 4      4 Ca                8431            13793  well_2 S_PUC…            4975 
#> 5      7 blank             2723             2359  well_1 blank             2723 
#> 6      8 blank             3456             8777  well_2 blank             3456 
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: `wstm (xc)_norm` <dbl>
```

**DATA**

```
text <- "
id_row  sample  'wsts (xc)_mean'  'wstm (xc)_mean'  label   tube
1       Ta      2937.5      4082.5      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4
2       Ta      3048        5347.5      well_1  S_PUC_C_064_(1)_G4
3       Ca      6176        7735.5      well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4
4       Ca      8431        13793       well_2  S_PUC_C_064_(4)_G4
7       blank   2723        2359        well_1  blank
8       blank   3456        8777        well_2  blank
"
dat <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach, it's looks that is working. However, I got the warnings that appears as ```warn = FALSE```. I read about it, and I wonder, should be a concern to me?

Comment: In general no. As a habit I add `warn=FALSE` to a reprex when loading `dplyr` to prevent that the warnings about conflicts clutters the reprex. More verbose it should be `warn.conflicts=FALSE` and it is an argument of the `library()` function.

Comment: Could be related with the NAs in the dataframe?